# forcing BibTex to display a certain key with an URL

Tags: bibtex, urls

it seems that my problem is the sum of many problem I saw in other topics.

I have an url in one of my Bibtex references

```
@misc{Notes,
author = {{Romolo}, G.},
title = {The Notes},
year = {last update: 2017-03-03}
url = {www.randomname.org/~ggg/opera}
}
```

The first problem I have is to make the ~. The few times I was able to display the url it didn't appear even using %7E.

The second problem is that when I compile my tex file with the Bibliography applescript, I'm not able to display this url.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks

GB

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. All formatting aspects are controlled by the bibliography style. Which bibliography style do you employ? Incidentally, there's a comma missing at the end of the `year` field.

Comment: wow, the comma was a big problem!
Now the url is diplayed! I still have troubles with the ~ though

Comment: Did you see the sentence in my answer, "Finally, if you're going to display URLs, it's a very good idea to load the `url` and/or `hyperref` packages"?

Comment: Thanks! something came up and I stopped working on it. But now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your sample bib entry contains a field called `url`, I will assume that you're using a bibliography style that knows how to format such a field. (Not all bibliography styles do, by the way!) In what follows, I'll assume you're using the `abbrvnat` bibliography style along with the `natbib` citation management package. I will further assume that you wish to generate "numeric" rather than "author-year" citation call-outs.

Before we proceed, do note that your sample bib entry contains two errors -- one syntactic, one of content. The syntax error is the missing comma at the end of the `year` field. Since commas are *required* to separate fields, a missing comma is going to generate a BibTeX error and crash. The content-related error is related to the fact that the `year` field is not meant to contain strings such as "last update: 2017-03-03". I suggest you change the name of the field from `year` to `note`.

Finally, if you're going to display URLs, it's a very good idea to load the `url` and/or `hyperref` packages.

Putting these ideas together yields the following MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
% generate a dummy bib file called 'mybib.bib'
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib} 
@misc{Notes,
author = {Romolo, G.},
title  = {The Notes},
note   = {Last update: 2017-03-03},
url    = {www.randomname.org/~ggg/opera}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % 'numeric' citation call-out style
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} % abbreviate authors' given names 
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document} 
\cite{Notes}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```